How "growing and preparing pineapples and pineapple products" should be read?
I saw this diagram description on a site. Is 'grow' a verb for both pineapples and pineapple products? How can products be grown?

The diagram below shows the process of growing and preparing
pineapples and pineapple products.


Pineapple products are grown and then processed. Beef is tissue that grows on or in a cow, but must then be processed to be sold.

No, grow is only for the pineapples. The sentence isn’t well written although it should be understood.  It’s better to say

The diagram below shows the process of growing pineapples and preparing pineapple products.

Edit
The diagram below shows the process of growing pineapples and preparing them and their products.
This way, growing is isolated from products, and preparing remains relevant to pineapples.

Yes, or maybe “…and preparing them and their products.”

Maybe that's what the original text meant, but preparing could also refer to the pineapples, as in "preparing pineapples for distribution and sale."

The diagram in the linked article shows some kind of 'preparation' (or processing) for each of the three pathways: pineapple juice, canned pineapple chunks, or waxed whole fruit. I'd leave the original text alone. It's fine.

Thanks, @Michael Harvey, Paul and Peter.  I’ve edited my answer.

Yours is better.
